# Subdomains resolving to main site URLs

Tags: .htaccess, cdn

I have subdomain on the site to host CDN images. Lets call it cdn.mysite.com.

Now all the pages on my site are also accessible in this fashion:

[www.mysite.com/examplepage.html](http://www.mysite.com/examplepage.html)

can also be accessed at

[cdn.mysite.com/examplepage.html](http://cdn.mysite.com/examplepage.html)

This is causing duplicate URLs in Google..

I am using Cloudflare with Edgecast CDN

Answer (score 0):

When you set up your subdomain, did you assign it a document root?

For example:

I set up the subdomain cohen.digitaldemo.net, whose document root is digitaldemo.net/cohen/

Anything OUTSIDE the /cohen folder on my site is inaccessible via cohen.digitaldemo.net.

Best,

Cynthia