# CDN URL indexed by google

Tags: php, .htaccess

I can see that google indexed my website using both the primary domain and the cdn domain, which means the same page can be accessed as www.example.com/page and cdn.example.com/page. I found this post [Subdomains resolving to main site URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857924/subdomains-resolving-to-main-site-urls) but there's no solution.

Any ideas on this issue? The best solution would be redirecting all subdomains (including www) to domain.com

Comment: Yes that's right just use 301 redirect all subdomains (including www) to `domain.com`

Comment: If you redirect from your CDN to the main URL, then what’s the point of _having_ a CDN in the first place? And _why_ are your pages themselves available via the CDN as well? That makes no sense to me.

Comment: It probably makes sense to have `cdn.site.com/images/` but not `cdn.site.com/`

Comment: Don't server by CDN what you want to server with your main domain, and vice versa, is what should have been done from the start. Right now, you indeed have a swath or permanent redirects to create, carefully redirecting from the main domain to the cdn what should be handled by the cdn, and redirecting from the cdn what should have been on the main domain. Just mirroring a site on a cdn might seem like an easy solution at the start, but it rarely is a good idea.

Comment: Do you know what a CDN is supposed to do? It's not really meant for serving your site. It's purpose is mostly for static content, e.g. stylesheets, images, videos, audio etc. It can help speed up the site with geographical locations because it's made for high availability and high performance.

Answer (score 0):

i used the following code in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^yourdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

found at http://codegarage.com/blog/2011/03/how-to-301-redirect-all-subdomains/